# How to convert a text file's line termination from Windows/DOS to Unix?

Tags: windows, linux, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert CRLF’s to line feeds on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux)

I have several scripts that produce a `/bin/sh^M bad interpreter` error message when they are run. I believe this is because they are formatted with the Windows/DOS line termination instead of the line termination expected by Unix/Linux (Ubuntu 9.04 for an embedded system in my case).

Is there an easy way to convert text files from the Windows/DOS format to the Unix format in a Linux environment?

Comment: same question with some alternate answers: http://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple choices here:

[**How do I convert between Unix and Windows text files?**](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html)

Comment: That page claims this about the dos2unix tools: "These utilities are available only on Solaris systems." This answer explains how to get similar tools in Linux environment: http://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux/52140#52140

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `dos2unix` utility for this.

```
dos2unix winfile.txt unixfile.txt
```

Comment: Dammit! I wrote an app to do this for me in C#. Then again, it also converted ANSI to Unicode and back again, so it wasn't a complete waste. +1

Comment: @randolph: you implemented iconv in C#?