# Convert CRLF's to line feeds on Linux

Tags: linux, carriage-return

What's the best way to convert *CRLF*'s to line feeds in files on Linux?

I've seen [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) commands, but is there anything simpler?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/38744/how-to-convert-a-text-files-line-termination-from-windows-dos-to-unix. The link provided in the accepted answer covers the dos2unix, perl and vi options among others.

Comment: This already has better answers though (so if one of these is to be closed, it should probably be that one)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use this command:

```
fromdos yourtextfile
```

The other way around:

```
todos yourtextfile
```

These commands are found in the **tofrodos** package (on most recent distributions), which also provides the two wrappers *unix2dos* and *dos2unix* that mimic the old unix tools of the same name.

Comment: +1 Much more useful than the currently top-voted "Use dos2unix" answer.

Comment: Yeah, even I'm voting this one up. Mine was more of a drive-by suggestion.

Comment: I would give extra bonus if you say how to make it recursive. Currently works only with wildcards.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea: something like `find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -null fromdos`

Comment: @Jonik what makes it "Much more useful"? Serious question

Comment: This helped me, the other one didn't. But I really don't remember what my use case was 5+ years ago. :P Also see the [original version](http://superuser.com/posts/52046/revisions) of the other answer.

Comment: @andrewtweber This answer also answers the very much related question of undoing the conversion and describes which package to install (which is a pain to find out). Also it gives a simple example of how to use the package, whereas the other answer seemed to just have copied the manpage, which is very beginner-unfriendly. Furthermore, the link in the answer is dead by now.

Comment: `fromdos` is not installed by default on Ubuntu: *"Command 'fromdos' not found"*

Answer (score 26):

Use [**`dos2unix`**](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html).

> dos2unix - DOS/MAC to UNIX text file format converter
>
> ```
> dos2unix  [options] [-c convmode] [-o file ...] [-n infile outfile ...]
>
> Options:
>           [-hkqV] [--help] [--keepdate] [--quiet] [--version]
> ```

Comment: and unix2dos for the other way 'round.

Comment: Consider elaborating on how to get this utility for your Linux system. At least on Ubuntu it's not installed by default (but by installing tofrodos package you get something very similar: http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/tofrodos).

Comment: Nowadays it looks like `unix2dos` should be preferred over `tofrodos`, as `tofrodos` seems to be abandoned since 2013 and `unix2dos` is still maintained. Also `unix2dos` has very detailed man page, which is a plus, and reading of it leaves a feeling of a well-thought tool.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer **perl**:

```
perl -lne 's/\r//g; print' winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

But that's well-suited to my uses, and it's very easy for me to remember.  Not all systems have a dos2unix command, but most that I work on have a perl interpreter.

Another is **recode**, a powerful replacement for dos2unix and iconv; it's available in the "recode" package in Debian repositories:

```
recode ibmpc..lat1 winfile.txt   # dos2unix
recode lat1..ibmpc unixfile.txt  # unix2dos
```

For **awk** fans:

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

...and **sed**:

```
sed 's/\r$//' winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

---

And now, only slightly-less-convoluted than deleting the CR's by hand in a hex editor, straight from [one of our stackoverflow.com friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532266/port-dos2unix-to-brainfuck/1534314#1534314), useable with the *beef* interpreter (located on your friendly neighborhood Debian repository),

dos2unix in **brainfuck**!

```
,[[->+>+<<]>>>,[<-------------[+++++++++++++.>>>]<[>>----------[>+++++++++++++.-------------]<++++++++++>]<<<<[-]>>>[-<<<+>>>]]<[-]<[-]<]++++++++++.
```

big thanks to jk for wasting an hour of his life to write this!

Comment: (useless use of cat and) perl is as complicated as sed... thus you are not really answering the question but rather collecting reputation :)

Comment: "best way" is subjective.  this works best for me (i'm tons more comfortable with perl than sed).  i didn't promise it would work best for you.

Comment: @akira: a question can have multiple valid answers.  I use this method as well, occasionally, mostly in combination with other changes, so it is definitely a valid answer; but "use dos2unix" is definitely the more practical answer in most situations.  So I think the ratings are fine.

Comment: @akira: if you find it simpler, please post it as an answer and enlighten the rest of us.

Comment: @~quack: that is the point: it is not simpler. thats the same for your perl answer. u2d or fromdos/todos are the right answers because they are _simpler_ than any stuff expressed in any other programming language.

Comment: look at quesion 46769 to get an idea what it means to give a correct AND simple answer.

Comment: @akira: stackoverflow, huh?  where've i heard of that before?

Comment: and now i am tempted to downvote this answer because you are constantly increasing the obsfucating level... (though i voted up 'my own' question on stackoverflow.com)

Comment: why not: perl -pe 's/\r//g' winfile.txt > unixfile.txt

Comment: I find it valid because "Not all systems have a dos2unix command, but most that I work on have a perl interpreter."

Answer (score 13):

I think you can use [`tr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29), as well (though I have no funny format files on which to try):

```sh
tr -d '\r' < file1 > file2
```

Comment: Preferred: tr should be available on any Linux system, whereas most of the other answers (fromdos, dos2unix etc.) are not necessarily present.  So unless you have sudo, they're less useful.  (Also preferred to Voigt and JustJeff's answer because this one avoids the superfluous cat--not that I have anything against the one sitting on my lap.)

Comment: @MikeMaxwell - [some](https://superuser.com/q/323060/978) people are opposed to the [uuoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), but it is rarely actually "[useless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16619430/4418)". And it's never ***wrong***. Sometimes it's more [performant](https://superuser.com/a/323066/978). I almost always use it for *readability* - which trumps any couple microseconds that might be saved by *not* including it :)

Comment: I don't disagree with you.  It also has an advantage if I'm liable to forget the file I want to read from (assuming I'm typing in from the command line) by the time I write the other part (in this case, by the time I write "tr -d '\r'").  And at my age, forgetting is all too common...  But that was the only thing I had to choose between this answer  and Voight/JustJeff's, which were otherwise identical.

Answer (score 10):

I do this on [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29):

```
cat cr_stuffed.file | tr -d \r > no_more_crs.file
```

Comment: nice.  i saw another mention of tr earlier today.  it's not a program that gets mentioned very often is it?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and `:set fileformat=unix`. While not the fastest, it does give me a preview.  It is especially useful in the case of a file with mixed endings.

Comment: Awesome! Worth mentioning, that `:set fileformat=dos` helps to convert to CRLF.

Answer (score 4):

In vi or [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29):

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

Comment: Corresponding Stack Overflow question: *[Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726)*

Answer (score 4):

I found a very easy way… Open file with nano: ## nano file.txt

press Ctrl+O to save, but before pressing Enter press:
Alt+D to toggle betwen DOS and Unix/Linux line-endings, or:
Alt+M to toggle betwen Mac and Unix/Linux line-endings
then press Enter to save and Ctrl+X to quit.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to clarify which toggle settings will replicate the behaviour requested by the OP?

Comment: The OP wants to toggle *off* DOS line endings, so `Alt+d`. Sometimes alt gets intercepted by the terminal program, so you can use `esc+d` instead.

Comment: Lots of nano shortcuts also work with Shift pressed, which often prevents terminal interception, so 'Alt-Shift-D' works too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a GUI method, try the [Kate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29) text editor (other advanced text editors may be able to handle this too). Open the *find* / *Replace* dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and replace `\r\n` with `\n`. (NB: you'll need to choose "Regular expression" from the drop down and deselect "Selection only" from the options.)

EDIT: Or, if you simply want to convert to Unix format, then use the menu option `Tools` > `End of Line` > `Unix`.

Comment: There are text editors, such as jEdit, that can do these transformations automatically - you just tell it if you want Unix, Windows or Mac line separators.

Comment: Actually, KATE can do that too through the *Tools > End of Line* menu. Maybe I should have thought more laterally than answering the question exactly as it was worded - but if you know you specifically want to convert `\r\n` to `\n` then using search/replace is easier than remembering which OS uses which line ending. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`CR LF` to `LF` using **awk**:

```sh
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 1
command | awk -v RS='\r?\n' 1
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 1 filename
```

Usage example:

```sh
echo -e 'foo\nbar\r\nbaz' | awk -v RS='\r?\n' 1 | hexdump -C
```

Explanation:

`-v RS='\r?\n'` sets variable RS (*input* **r**ecord **s**eparator) to `\r?\n`, meaning input is read line by line separated by LF (`\n`) which may (`?`) be preceded by CR (`\r`).

`1` is the script awk executes. A script consists of `condition { action }`. In this case, `1` is the condition which evaluates to true. The action is omitted, so the default action is executed, which means *print the current line* (which could also be written as `{print $0}` or simply `{print}`).

---

`LF` to `CR LF`: You can set the variable `ORS` (***o***utput **r**ecord **s**eparator) to modify the line ends of the output. Example:

```sh
echo -e 'foo\nbar\r\nbaz' | awk -v RS='\r?\n' -v ORS='\r\n' 1 | hexdump -C
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into **dos2unix.py** Python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""\
convert dos linefeeds (crlf) to unix (lf)
usage: dos2unix.py <input> <output>
"""
import sys

if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 2:
  sys.exit(__doc__)

content = ''
outsize = 0
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as infile:
  content = infile.read()
with open(sys.argv[2], 'wb') as output:
  for line in content.splitlines():
    outsize += len(line) + 1
    output.write(line + '\n')

print("Done. Saved %s bytes." % (len(content)-outsize))
```

Should work on any platform with Python installed. Public domain.

Answer (score 1):

Use Perl's generic `\R` in a regex. That way, you can convert files with any of CR, CRLF or already LF or a mix of them (yes, there are files which mix 2 different newline conventions!).

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\R/\n/g' $yourfile
```

(`-i.bak` tells perl to convert the file in-place, saving the original as `${yourfile}.bak`)

More info on `\R` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56703060/111036)

Answer (score 0):

I used this script for files I needed to emergency transfer files from a windows system to a unix system.

```
 find . -type f | xargs file | grep CRLF | cut -d: -f1 | xargs dos2unix
```

`find . -type f`

Finds all the files, recursively in the directory you're running the command from

`xargs file`

Pass it to the [file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) program to get an analysis of the file.

`grep CRLF`

We only want the output of [file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) that shows CRLF.

`cut -d: -f1`

Get the output up to to the color. discard the rest. We should only have a filename now

`xargs dos2unix`

Pass the filename to the program [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) using [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).