# Commandline tool to convert between text formats

Tags: linux, command-line, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Batch-convert files for encoding or line ending](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending)

Since I often work with source code and [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) documents written either on Windows, Linux and OS X I was looking for a simple command-line tool available for Linux and OS X which allows me to quickly convert from a format to another... I'm sure it must exist!

Something like:

```
convert -from utf8 -to iso8859-1 oldfile.tex newfile.tex
```

Is there something useful for my purpose?

In addition, it would be nice to have something that is able to guess which text format is used within a document. The final answer would be a tool able to to both things :)

Comment: this has been asked many times before.  see the duplicate and its "linked questions" sidebar for variations.

Comment: (the answer to your "bonus question", which may not be immediately obvious in the existing answers, is **file**.)

Comment: See also *[Convert CRLF's to line feeds on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/52044)*.