# How can I convert "DOS" .txt file to Unix .txt file

Tags: linux, conversion, ms-dos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert CRLF's to line feeds on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux)

How can I convert a DOS text file to Unix text file, so I can use my Linux parser properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) is a tool for converting line endings.

Answer (score 2):

Most Unix installations include the '[tr](http://ss64.com/bash/tr.html)' command ('tr' is short for 'translate') - you could use that to convert your input file with DOS text to output Unix text format:

tr -d '\r' < dos.txt > unix.txt

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

On Debian-derived (Ubuntu, etc) systems, you want the `tofrodos` package, which provides the commands `todos` and `fromdos`. (`fromdos` is the one you are looking for.)

On RedHat-derived systems (RHEL, Centos, Fedora, etc), you want the `dos2unix` package, which provides the commands `dos2unix` and `mac2unix`. To convert in the other direction, you'll want the `unix2dos` package, which provides the `unix2dos` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "how do I convert a plain-text file in DOS format to a plain-text file in UNIX format", try the [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) command.

Comment: My Ubuntu does not have it, how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of [how to use antiword to extract the text](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/08/use-antiword-to-extract-text-from-doc-files/).

Answer (score 0):

Some systems have a `dos2unix` command.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: You want to convert Windows text files into Linux text files? If yes: There's a utility `dos2unix` that will do the job for you.