# getting "command not found" when using source command on Fedora

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I am using Fedora. When I issue:

```
-bash-3.2$ source na-profile.conf
```

I get:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

The na-profile.conf file looks like:

```
KEYTAB=server02 export KEYTAB;
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/xxxx/11.2.0.1/yyyyy; export ORACLE_HOME;
TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin; export TNS_ADMIN;
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

There are no extra lines or spaces in the file.

Comment: There is a missing ; on line 1 after server02.

Comment: I put the semicolon in and I get the same result

Comment: "set -x" before the source command to see how bash expands the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by having MS-DOS line endings in `na-profile.conf`

The shell is trying to use the `^M` character as a command, and reports that it cannot be found.

You might have created the file using a Windows editor?

Convert the file to have unix line endings and the problem will resolve.

Instructions here:
[Convert CRLF's to line feeds on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux)