# Convert Unix line endings to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, text-editing, newlines, file-conversion

I recently moved back to Windows from Linux. I have some files with CRLFs, some with LFs and some that are mixed. Is there a utility that will help me find all my Unix-touched files and convert them to proper CRLF terminated files?

The utility must run on Windows, not Linux. I have already moved. I'd rather not install [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) if I can avoid it.

Comment: related: see http://superuser.com/questions/38744 http://superuser.com/questions/27060 http://superuser.com/questions/52044 ... any tool mentioned in those can be reversed to accomplish what you want to do

Comment: Duplicate question

Comment: The solutions in those so called Duplicate questions all run on linux platforms or preform the opposite conversion. I don't have linux any more. I have windows.

Comment: they are all available for Windows via Cygwin, GnuWin32, UnxUtils or the like.  i believe there are Powershell scripts that can do this as well, though i don't know enough about it to provide any links.

Comment: @quack: The question specifically states that the user is looking for something that will do the job on Windows, using a Windows utility.

Comment: duplicates: [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17579553/995714), [Way to convert CR to CRLF in the text file for all the lines using CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19912941/995714)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can convert them with the `unix2dos` utility on your Linux platform. There are `unix2dos` [versions available for Windows](http://www.bastet.com/) as well.

If you have Perl installed you can also use this one liner:

```sh
perl -p -e 's/\n/\r\n/' < UNIX_LF.txt > WINDOWS_CRLF.txt
```

Comment: I did something similar to this, but I used python.

Comment: @Matthew Scouten: so... you found a unix utility that runs on windows! congrats!

Comment: yes and no. I WROTE my own blasted utility. I could have done this from the start, but I was hoping to save 30 mins. Unfortunately I was not happy with any utilities available. The closest I found corrupted any binary files in the directory.

Comment: There are problems converting with dos2unix and unix2dos - if the file has mixed CRLF and LF there may be some occurences that wouldn't be replaced.

Comment: Just don't run it twice on the same file, it would replace `\n` with `\r\r\n`.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an easy and quick way.

Drag and drop the text file into Chrome (I don't know about other browsers) and then cut and paste back into the original file :)

Comment: hehe… this answer made me lol

Comment: all browsers can read Unix line endings just fine, including IE. But even then wordpad can also do that, and so will [modern Notepad](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/). What's important here is how to convert multiple files automatically

Comment: This does not answer the question - it describes just a workaround.

Answer (score 10):

The one I found best for recursively going through folders, allowing file filters and allowing a simple search for "\r\n" and replacing it with just "\n" was [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B).

Notepad++ is one of the best, free, open source notepad programs for Windows. It is very simple and powerful. It handled the line ending search/replace just fine. A contractor check a bunch of .c and .h files in to our repository with Linux \r\n line endings, but since most people have standardized on Windows/Eclipse build tools, the files won't build until the line endings are converted.

Comment: I think you reversed the endings there: linux is \n, windows is \r\n

Comment: Notepad++ also has a simple `Edit -> EOL Conversion` menu if the number of files to convert is small.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [Swiss File Knife](http://swissfileknife.sourceforge.net/).

For example: `sfk addcr -dir . -file .txt -norec`
changes LF endings into CR/LF for Windows,
on all .txt files of the current directory,
but NOT within subdirectories (no recursion).

But this program does a lot more than just that.

Comment: I don't specify `-norec` because I want recursion to happen but it doesn't seem like it

Answer (score 8):

On Cygwin, you can convert between Unix and "DOS" AKA Windows files using two built-in utilities:

Convert to DOS CR/LF format:

```
u2d filename
```

Convert back to Unix CR format:

```
d2u filename
```

The file is left in place with the same name.

Enjoy!
Rick

Comment: This is sometimes called `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` in case you cannot find it as u2d or d2u. There is also `unix2mac`

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to throw this solution out there. Git will do this. [See this post about it](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

So theoretically you could do this to convert an entire tree

```
cd root/of/tree
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
echo "* text eol=crlf" > .gitattributes
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

Change `crlf` to `lf` if you want to go the other way. NOTE: you're not done yet, keep reading

Type `git status` to see which files will be affected. You might have to add lines like

```
*.jpg binary
*.png binary
*.gif binary
```

etc to `.gitattributes` to avoid converting certain files. You can also explicit mark certain files as text

```
*.md text
*.css text
```

Then just repeat these 2 lines after you've edited `.gitattributes`

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

Then use `git status` again to see which files will be changed. When you're sure all the files you want affected are listed by `git status` then commit

```
git add .
git commit -m "normalize line endings"
```

now check all the files out again

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

They should now have whatever your desired line endings are

** NOTE: If you were already using git skip the first 3 commands git commands. If you were not using git you can now delete the `.gitattributes` file and the `.git` folder.

** Back up your files: the `git rm --cached -r` deletes them all (although they are theoretically in your git repo (the .git folder) which is how they get restored by the last command `git reset --hard`. It's just since files are getting deleted it's probably best to back them up.

Answer (score 2):

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_between_newline_formats) there's a solution in cmd:

```bat
TYPE unix_file | FIND /V "" > dos_file
```

In PowerShell there are various ways to do that by reversing what was done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19127741/995714).

```powershell
PS> (Get-Content $file -Raw).Replace("`n", "`r`n") | Set-Content $path -Force

PS> (Get-Content $infile) -join "`r`n" > $outfile

PS> $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($original_file) -replace "`n", "`r`n"
PS> [IO.File]::WriteAllText($original_file, $text)
```

It's also possible to do this in [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12733165/995714) and [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) which are also tools that are already available in Windows without installing a third-party application.

Comment: The PowerShell code snippet helped me. Ta

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor that understands both line endings like [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html), or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) if you don't need to convert all line ending in all your files, but just don't want to see the entire file bunched up on the first line.

Comment: That's what they said when I had the inverse problem while switching to linux. I kept running into tools that had problems with the wrong line endings. And NOTHING handles mixed line endings reasonably.

Comment: @Matthew I know the scite handle [unix / windows](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#LineEndings) line endings correctly. I use it for that purpose in the windows vms I run in linux when editing files on the host system.

Comment: I am sure that the editors you recommend will work just fine. but at some point, I will need to feed the textfile to some other tool, and that tool will NOT. At that point, having a text editor that handles things well will make it worse by hiding the problem. and I will bet that it still handles mixed endings badly (or at least with quirks).

Comment: +1 for the notepad++ option to convert lie endings. And here is how to do more specifically (see "method 2") : http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/brippe/csci123/saveAsUnix.aspx

Comment: Notepad++ already have the solutions to convert line endings, encodings among other things

Answer (score 1):

Get [AWK for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

Convert Unix line endings to Windows line endings:

```sh
awk 'sub("$", "\r")' unixfile.txt > winfile.txt
```

Convert Windows line endings to Unix line endings:

```sh
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

Older versions of `awk` do not include the `sub` function. In such cases, use the same command, but replace `awk` with `gawk` or `nawk`.

[Source](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to translate the eoln characters in TEXT files, and everyone has a favourite.

But I always transfer files from Linux to Windows in BINARY mode, then I open TEXT files in Windows with an editor capable of opening both types, and saving them in either form, if necessary.

I used Programmers File Editor for this, but Notepad++ can do it too. WordPad is also useful [at least, for *viewing* LF terminated files].

I'm thinking of the simple text files which may have originated on Linux, and need to be readable in the (defacto standard) world of Windows. I'm not sure what you meant by 'unix-touched files'.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it only does one file at a time.

Comment: 'unix-touched files' is my word for both LF-only and mixed CRLF-LF files. Once a file has been edited in unix-oid tools, it tends to get 'infected' with LF-only lines.

Comment: What I was *really* saying was that by choosing the right software for viewing text files, they don't have to be converted at all. BTW, I avoided taking you to task for describing CRLF terminated files as 'proper'. It depends entirely on your viewpoint. Each method is proper in its own OS. When a file is moved to a different OS, then we find that Win/Mac/Linux are all different. I suspect that the Unix/Linux method is the original one.

Comment: You suspect wrong. ASCII standard was originally developed for teletype machines, and mandated CRLF. Most internet protocols (including HTTP, SMTP, FTP, IRC and many others) also require CRLF endings (most implementations accept bare LF for compatibility with non-compliant Unix programs). In this case, Windows is following the standard and Unix and Mac are breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

To offer more options (even though I best enjoyed [user45832's hack answer](https://superuser.com/a/174539/160219)):

**Online convertors**

- http://www.myriap.com/en/apps/text_converter_windows_linux_mac
- http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php

**[I guess a GUI FTP program](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux) [will do it automatically](http://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-files-from-linux-format-windows/)**

**Batch/DOS one-liner *(removes empty lines)*:**

```
FOR /F "eol= delims= usebackq" %a IN (infile.txt) DO (ECHO %a>> outfile.txt)
```

**Powershell:**

```
gc infile.txt | %{$_.split("`n")} | Out-File outfile.txt
```

Got the last two [from here](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/227963-file-lf-crlf-conversion-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score -1):

My Linux distribution has two little utilities called `fromdos` and `todos` that I use for this task.

Comment: The OP is asking for a *Windows tool*

Answer (score -2):

I used to open the file in 'edit' and save as that the job was done ...

Comment: what's "edit"? there's no such tool in windows 10

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/edithlp.htm

Comment: obviously I've used `edit` in DOS but this question is about **Windows**

Comment: `edit` used to be part of Windows up to `Windows XP`. My answer is about 8 years old. In that time `edit` was part of Windows installation in many cases ...

Answer (score -2):

For me in windows10 on 2020 I just rename the file from "file" to "file.txt"
Best solution I guess.

Comment: **Please do not ask for upvotes.** It is **unnecessary** and actually considered to be rude. If this answer did not contain an obvious grammatical error. It would receive more positive attention.

Comment: Really?  Please explain, how does this solution change the file contents?  Please explain _why_ you believe your solution works.

Comment: I move the text file from linux ubuntu to windows 10 and rename the type to be .txt file.
Than I notice the file was 100% converted to .txt with no errors or anything.
Just rename the type at the end. Make sure you have enable on windows file type extensions for this to work.

Comment: rename a file never changes its content. A few only places where it "works" is in git because git does automatic line-ending conversion

Comment: my answer is for those want to convert their Linux text files to windows txt files and believe it needs an utility converter when they need just to rename the file to .txt