# What is the easiest way to convert a bunch of text files from LF (Unix) to CRLF (Windows) in a single run?

Tags: windows, unix, newlines

There is a directory tree on a **Windows7** machine containing a few hundred text files that I want to convert from LF to CRLF.

I already found a Win32 version of [UNIX2DOS](http://www.bastet.com/) but that one accepts only one file at a time for input whereas I want to convert a whole set of directories and subdirectories **recursively in a single run**.

What is the easiest way to accomplish that task?

Comment: most tools will happily accept multiple files as input, like `unix2dos *.txt` [Convert Unix line endings to Windows](https://superuser.com/q/71507/241386)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for one directory, open a command-prompt window, `cd` to the desired folder and

```
for %f in (*.txt) do UNIX2DOS %f ...
```

or for all subdirectories use the /R option

```
for /R %f in (*.txt) do UNIX2DOS %f ...
```

It may be worth remembering that, unlike notepad, editors like wordpad and notepad++ are happy with LF as line endings.

If you are converting a bunch of text files, you might also consider converting to UTF-8 using something like `recode` or `iconv`.