# How to convert DOS line endings to UNIX on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to create a file with Linux line endings in a Windows command script.

The closest I can get so far is this PowerShell one-liner:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-ChildItem -File "D:\path\file.sh" | % { $x = get-content -raw -path $_.fullname; $x -replace [char[]](13),'' | set-content -path $_.fullname }"
```

This is so close to what I want... the fly in the ointment is that it adds an extra CR+LF at the end of the file! Any suggestions for how I can fix this, or alternative techniques? I can't install any additional software such as Cygwin or dos2unix as this is for a locked-down production environment.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128003/2579220, the last comment mentions `Set-Content -NoNewline`.

Comment: I'm running v4, -NoNewline is not available.

Comment: The other way: *[Convert Unix line endings to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/71507)*

Comment: there are many solutions in the other duplicate that requires no 3rd party tool, did you even read it? like `` (Get-Content $file -Raw).Replace("`r`n", "`n") | Set-Content $path -Force ``

Comment: @phuclv YOU didn't even read the post you're linking to... Firstly, that post is about the inverse operation than what OP is asking. Secondly, the comment precisely before yours already links this question. And this is not the first time I see you doing this. Stop being an absolute jerk to everyone on SO, and start paying attention to what you're interacting with...

Comment: @adamency you don't even know that it's an automatic message from stackexchange when closing questions? And yes it applies for the reverse direction as well, just exchange the replacement strings. Did you even read my previous comment? It was unfortunately messed up due to Markdown in comments but it works correctly

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution I could find is:

```
((Get-Content $file) -join "`n") + "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline $file
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127741/replace-crlf-using-powershell/48919146#48919146)

Comment: Not the best solution for large files. Reading, converting and writing line by line is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you need :

```
powershell.exe -noninteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {[IO.File]::WriteAllText('file_lfonly.txt', ([IO.File]::ReadAllText('file_crlf.txt') -replace \"`r`n\", \"`n\"))};"
```