# How to draw ASCII art through cmd to textfile(notepad)?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, notepad, ascii-art

I was exploring the banner command on linux and am wondering to use something of that sort to put into text files in Windows10. I have tried cowsay and figlet, didn't like the cow/tux talking to me and had compatibility issues with figlet.

Would be happy if anyone could suggest a command line way to put the ASCII art to text files on Windows cmd. Something like

```
echo HELLOWORLD | command > file.txt
```

rather than copy-pasting art from other means.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIGlet and ASCII Art Generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/figletgenerator/) runs well on Windows 10 v. 1809. However,it has a simple GUI, rather than being executable from CMD. That said, the GUI calls the standard figlet DLL's, so you might try using the same calls you've tried for for figlet.

BTW, though the program comes inside an installer, it can also be used by opening the installer in 7-Zip and unpacking to a new folder.

[image: FIGlet and ASCII Art Generatore]

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility issues you are having are likely due to line-ending encodings and relatively easy to resolve in Linux.  See [Convert Unix line endings to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/71507/convert-unix-line-endings-to-windows)